# Using lag and filter in R

Tags: r

Below is a sample of a dataset which looks like this:

| User | Page | Click |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Home | Enter |
| 123 | Message | Enter |
| 123 | Message | FormChange |
| 123 | Message | NameChange |
| 123 | Message | FormChange |
| 123 | Message | FormChange |
| 123 | Message | FormChange |
| 123 | Message | Submit |
| 123 | Home | Enter |

I was able to convert the above table to the below table with this code:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(User) %>%
  mutate(Activity = case_when(Click == "Enter" ~ Page,
                              lag(Page) == Page ~ Click)) %>%
  filter(Activity != lag(Activity, 1) | is.na(lag(Activity, 1))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

| User | Activity |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Home |
| 123 | Message |
| 123 | FormChange |
| 123 | NA |
| 123 | FormChange |
| 123 | Submit |
| 123 | Home |

For some reason, the NameChange click does not appear in the data instead, I see NA for all instances in the dataset.

How do I correct my code?

Thank you.

Comment: It runs ok for me using dplyr 1.0.9. Is there some invisible difference between the "Message" text in the FormChange vs NameChange rows, e.g. extra space? It seems Page != lag(Page) there.

Comment: @JonSpring Which package or add-in have you used to import the data ? Have you read the Rmarkdown table ?

Comment: I copied your table and used the `datapasta` addin to turn it into a data frame. It will be easier to help if you can share example data as code we can run rather than a table of what it looks like. If you run `dput(df1)` that will create a code recipe you can include in the body of your question.